# Do speakers of less-common languages find it harder to understand foreigners?

Tags: language-barrier

I, as a native speaker of English, am quite familiar with the pronunciation quirks of people of many different nationalities when they speak English. I have heard in passing people from probably half or more of the countries in the world speaking English; be it in person, on television, at work or passing in the street. On occasion I've had to converse with people who have strong accents and less-than-fluent language skills (credit to them; I speak no other languages beyond a very basic level). I conclude from this that in general, native English speakers are likely to be familiar with a diverse range of people speaking English and are relatively able to understand them*

My question is: For people whose native language has minimal adoption as a second language around the world; does this noticeably impede their ability to understand a foreigner speaking perhaps a rudimentary form of their language, when they encounter them? In other words, where encountering non-native speakers of that language is rare, does this necessarily mean that most native speakers will find them hard to understand when they are encountered, due to lack of familiarity?

If so, what can the second-language speaker do to mitigate problems in mutual understanding, if such a generalisation is possible?

(*on the other hand, I noticed that even west coast Americans failed to understand a word I said on the first pass in my more-or-less standard southern British accent when I visited, so perhaps high intelligibility of English is far from a given)

Comment: I'm not certain if this is a travel related question or an english related question, I would suggest moving this to https://english.stackexchange.com/ or https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I do agree this is not really a travel question but have not moved it yet, as I do not know the possible target stacks and would like to know which one is the best option.

Comment: I do not agree that English language speakers are more likely to hear more different accents, as a person speaking English as second language I have more experience with hearing different English accents than many of my native language English speaker friends.

Comment: @Willeke I beg your pardon, what I mean is as compared to native speakers of another language that is not commonly spoken as a second language. Most native English speakers can identify from memory a number of stereotypical 'foreign' accents as heard when speaking English. My assumption is that this is unlikely to be true *in the context of their own language* for those whose native language is rarely spoken by foreigners. I would appreciate if you could indicate how you think my statement of the premise could be improved to make it clearer.

Comment: @Max I think the crucial point is the question **What can a second-language speaker do?** because it doesn't refer to English, but any language a traveller may encounter that isn't their native tongue.

Comment: @TomW, I think your starting point, (native language) is much less important than many other points. Traveling and meeting people from other areas and hearing other accents is a main one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as it's about language and a better fit on [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Giorgio as I have explained twice now, the question is *not* about English.

Comment: After reading the body of the question, I realized this wasn’t asking about English. I hope the closevoters had done the same.

Comment: @Giorgio I agree that this is off-topic but it's also off-topic on EL&U.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's purely about language and has no travel aspect except insofar as the fact that travelling is the time one is most likely to hear foreigners speaking.

Comment: An interesting question for Linguistics, it has more to do with the internal variety of the language and not it's 'commonness'.

Comment: Although it' would be an interesting theoretical question for linguists, this one is an interesting practical question for travellers.